# Is it possible to block print calls in java?

Tags: java, printing, console-output

if a method is called but the method calls System.out.print(); and prints on the console, is there any way to disable printing on console for that specific method calls and enable again

Comment: Redirect System.out to a location other than the standard output, such as to a file.

Comment: What you seem to really be looking for is passing an `InputStream` as a method parameter.